# django html5 cache in django 1.7

Tags: django, html5-appcache

I've got some problems implementing 3rd party django package [django-html5-appcache](https://django-html5-appcache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

Documentation especify that migrate command must be executed, but when i execute command:

`python manage.py migrate html5_appcache`

Outputs:

> "No migrations to apply"

However I decided to complete installation steps. but testing it maniffest file appears to be empty (according to docs, urls suppose to autodiscover):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version: $0$
# date: $-$


NETWORK:
*
```

And Chrome Console Outputs:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest.appcache
127.0.0.1/:1 Application Cache Checking event
127.0.0.1/:1 Application Cache Downloading event
127.0.0.1/:1 Application Cache Progress event (0 of 0) 
127.0.0.1/:1 Application Cache Cached event
```

Im using Django 1.7

Any body has expirience with this django package?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're supposed to put the following code in your `urls.py` to get autodiscover.

```
Enable appcache discovery by adding the lines below in urls.py:

import html5_appcache
html5_appcache.autodiscover()
```

(Source: documentation here: https://django-html5-appcache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

Also, `python manage.py migrate` commands are used to alter the DB structure and should not affect your `urls.py`.

Comment: yes i know , I'm not suggesting that no migrations applied are affecting my urls.py. The problem Is that package is not working properly, and is strange that doc suggest to apply migraiton command but no migrations seems to be available